# How to skip display data from API into collection view cell if count equals 0

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing data from an API into a collection view in which there is a field named `count`. I don't want to display data whose `count` is 0 and I would like the other collection view cells to rearrange accordingly.

screenshot of assets folder:
[image: screenshot of assets folder]

my screenshot for result
[image: result of my app when it starts]

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {


//MARK: IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var store_bar: UIViewX!
@IBOutlet weak var store_title: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var category_title: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var category_bar: UIViewX!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryColView: UICollectionView!

var selectedBtnIndex:Int = 1

var categoryData = [ModelCategories]()
var storeData = [ModelStore]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // register collectionview cell
    self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "CategoryCell1", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1")
    self.categoryColView.register(UINib(nibName: "StoresCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell")

    self.store_bar.isHidden = true

    self.getCategoriesList()
    self.getStoreList()

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

@objc func click_Category(sender: UIButton!) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }
}

@objc func click_store(sender: UIButton!) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }
}


//MARK: IBActions

@IBAction func categoriesData(_ sender: UIButton) {

    selectedBtnIndex = 1
    self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
    self.store_bar.isHidden = true
    self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    self.category_bar.isHidden = false
    self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    self.categoryColView.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func storeData(_ sender: UIButton) {

    selectedBtnIndex = 2
    self.categoryColView.isHidden = false
    self.store_bar.isHidden = false
    self.store_title.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    self.category_bar.isHidden = true
    self.category_title.setTitleColor(UIColor(rgb: 0xAAAAAA), for: .normal)
    self.categoryColView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func showHomeScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}

@IBAction func toSearchPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchPageController") as! SearchPageController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}

func getCategoriesList() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)
        APIClient<ModelBaseCategoryList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_CategoriesList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                self.categoryData.removeAll()
                let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.categories! as NSArray

                if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                    for i in modelResponse.categories! {
                        self.categoryData.append(i)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.categoryColView.reloadData()
        }) { (failed) in
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
    }
}

func getStoreList() {
    if ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.isReachable() {
        ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StartProgress(view: self.view)
        APIClient<ModelBaseStoreList>().API_GET(Url: SD_GET_StoreList, Params: [:], Authentication: true, Progress: true, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (modelResponse) in

            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)

            if(modelResponse.success == true) {

                self.storeData.removeAll()
                let resul_array_tmp_new = modelResponse.store! as NSArray

                if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
                    for i in modelResponse.store! {
                        self.storeData.append(i)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                self.view.makeToast(modelResponse.message)
            }
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.categoryColView.reloadData()
        }) { (failed) in
            ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.StopProgress(view: self.view)
            self.view.makeToast(failed.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.makeToast("No Internet Connection..")
    }
}
}


    //MARK: Delegate and Data Source Methods
    extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
        return categoryData.count
    }else {
        return storeData.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1

        let dict = categoryData[indexPath.row]

        if let catName = dict.name, catName.count != 0 {
            cell.categoryName.text = catName
        }

        if let catOffersCount = dict.count {
            if catOffersCount <= 1 {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offer"
                cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "tickets")
            }else {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offers"
            }
        }

        if dict.slug == "mens" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "MENS")
        } else if dict.slug == "electronics" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "ELECTRONICS")
        }else if dict.slug == "beauty" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "BEAUTY")
        }else if dict.slug == "fashion" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "FASHION")
        }else if dict.slug == "kids-clothing" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "KIDS FASHION")
        }else if dict.slug == "travel" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "TRAVEL")
        }else if dict.slug == "womens-apparels" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "WOMENS APPARELS")
        }else if dict.slug == "eyewear" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "EYEWEAR")
        }else {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "tickets")
        }


        cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
        cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! StoresCell

        let dict = storeData[indexPath.row]

        if let storeName = dict.name, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storeName.text = storeName
        }

        if let storeOfferCount = dict.count {
            cell.storeOfferCount.text = "\(storeOfferCount)"+" "+"Offers"
        }

        cell.store_btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
        cell.store_btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_store), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
       return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3, height: 93)
    }else {
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3, height: 93)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a condition in response methods like this to eliminate the data with count property equals to 0.

```
if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
    for i in modelResponse.store! {
        if i.count != 0 {
            self.storeData.append(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Same for categories list.

```
if resul_array_tmp_new.count > 0 {
    for i in modelResponse.categories! {
        if i.count != 0 {
            self.categoryData.append(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello sir can u help me another problem. i have 74 images for 74 categories but images are not coming from api so i need to hardcode it how do i do it the easiest way and i need to assign image according to the field name slug in category api given in my code above

Comment: sure, give an example of the category name and your image name.

Comment: category name lets say Mens and image name is MENS.png. this is for only 1 there are lots of other and slug = mens in api like this {
            "object_id": 6818,
            "term_taxonomy_id": 554,
            "term_order": 0,
            "term_id": 554,
            "taxonomy": "offer_categories",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "count": 6,
            "name": "Mens",
            "slug": "mens",
            "term_group": 0,
            "ID": 554
        },

Comment: do you want his in your category response method?

Comment: yes when app starts i want to show image, category, offer count

Comment: category and offer count are showing because they are coming from api so its easy to deal with

Comment: you can do somthing like this *code starts from here*

  var arrCategoryImages = [UIImage]()
        for i in modelResponse.categories! {
            if i.count != 0 {
                arrCategoryImages.append(UIImage(named: "\(i.slug).png")!)
                self.categoryData.append(i)
            }
        }

Comment: or add a property in your model ModelCategories and then assign images in your loop *code starts from here*

        for i in modelResponse.categories! {
            if i.count != 0 {
                i.image = UIImage(named: "(i.slug).png"!
                self.categoryData.append(i)
            }
        }

Comment: boss has told me to hardcode it.i told him that put images on server so that its easy to display without making so much for loops

Comment: you should write in getCategoriesList this method

Comment: i wrote but it throws an error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

Comment: and in cellforrow method i wrote  cell.categoryImage.image = arrCategoryImages[indexPath.row]

Comment: have you added images in your assets?

Comment: can you send me your images so that i'll try to make it correct for you

Comment: have uploaded my assets pic

Comment: how do i send it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195080/discussion-between-nishant-narola-and-muhammad-maaz-ul-haq).

Comment: If you have a second problem... open a second question. Comments are not supposed to be used for asking additional questions as they do not help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
    return (categoryData.count > 0) ? categoryData.count : 0
}else {
    return (storeData.count > 0) ? storeData.count : 0
}}
```

and also change cellForRowAt IndexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if selectedBtnIndex == 1{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell1

    if categoryData.count > indexPath.row {
        let dict = categoryData[indexPath.row]

        if let catName = dict.name, catName.count != 0 {
            cell.categoryName.text = catName
        }

        if let catOffersCount = dict.count {
            if catOffersCount <= 1 {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offer"
                cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "tickets")
            }else {
                cell.catOfferCount.text = "\(catOffersCount)"+" "+"Offers"
            }
        }

        if dict.slug == "mens" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "MENS")
        } else if dict.slug == "electronics" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "ELECTRONICS")
        }else if dict.slug == "beauty" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "BEAUTY")
        }else if dict.slug == "fashion" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "FASHION")
        }else if dict.slug == "kids-clothing" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "KIDS FASHION")
        }else if dict.slug == "travel" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "TRAVEL")
        }else if dict.slug == "womens-apparels" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "WOMENS APPARELS")
        }else if dict.slug == "eyewear" {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "EYEWEAR")
        }else {
            cell.categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: "tickets")
        }


        cell.btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        cell.btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
        cell.btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_Category), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    return cell
}else {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoresCell", for: indexPath) as! StoresCell
    if storeData.count > indexPath.row {
        let dict = storeData[indexPath.row]

        if let storeName = dict.name, storeName.count != 0 {
            cell.storeName.text = storeName
        }

        if let storeOfferCount = dict.count {
            cell.storeOfferCount.text = "\(storeOfferCount)"+" "+"Offers"
        }

        cell.store_btn_click.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_unchecked"), for: .normal)
        cell.store_btn_click.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_checked"), for: .selected)
        cell.store_btn_click.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click_store), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    return cell
}}
```